# one ajax request, multiple response?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

ok here is what I'm doing. check out the php and java script script below

**PHP**

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); 

$client = new SoapClient("server/test.wsdl");  

$origtext = array('user'=>$_GET['pointname']); 
$lastmodif    = isset($_GET['timestamp']) ? $_GET['timestamp'] : 0;
$currentmodif = $client->getTime($origtext)->{"timest"};

while ($currentmodif <= $lastmodif) // check if the data file has been modified
{
  // sleep(1);
  usleep(10000); // sleep 10ms to unload the CPU
  clearstatcache();
  $currentmodif = $client->getTime($origtext)->{"timest"};
}

$response = array(); 
$response['msg']       = $client->getMobile($origtext)->{"phone-num"};
$response['timestamp'] = $currentmodif;

echo json_encode($response); 

flush();
```

**Javascript**

```
var timestamp = 0;
var pointname = "test1";
var noerror = true;

function wait() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "backend.php",
        data: "timestamp=" + this.timestamp + "&pointname=" + pointname,
        success: function (transp) {
            var response = eval('(' + transp + ')');
            timestamp = response['timestamp'];
            $("#page1b").html(response['msg']);
            $("#page1c").html(timestamp);
            noerror = true;
        },
        complete: function (transp) {
            if (!noerror) setTimeout(function () {
                wait()
            }, 5000);
            else wait();
            noerror = false;
        }
    });
}
wait();
```

once the ajax request is fired, from the server side will do a while loop check time value until time has changed, then it will echo a new value back to client and display on the webpage.(and all this will be automatically, and not much memory consuming on client side ) my ultimate target is to build a table  with 100 value inside,  firing 100 ajax request is obviously impossible. I want to treat those values separately but all sharing the same php script, meaning each value will only change when it changed and not affected by the others, but only one php script shown above required. any advice?

Comment: Does it work? I'm not a PHP guy, but I would've thought that PHP code would produce a single response that just took a really long time.

Comment: Rather than mucking about with this `wait()` stuff, you should just pass in a callback function to run on `complete`. Functional programming can be really elegant when you use it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. In older browsers this was possible, and there was even a [JQuery plug-in](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ajax-http-stream) to facilitate it, but newer browser only fire the event when the whole request is received, and don't allow you to read the partial response before that.